# Express appears to be ignoring controller for root route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-routing

I am attempting to send all `GET` requests on my site (other than API requests) to a controller which checks for the presence of a signed-in user before showing the page. Otherwise, if not currently signed in, the user is sent to the sign-in page.

The below structure works perfectly for everything but the root route (`'/'`). For example, if I try to hit `/admin` or `/games` as a non signed-in user I am properly sent to the sign-in page. Likewise, if I am signed in each page shows properly (note: I am using AngularJS client-side). The one issue I have is that when I hit my root route the app attempts to show `index.html` without ever checking if the user is signed in. I'm confused as to why that route is handled differently, and why my `pagesController` is seemingly never invoked for this route. I've done some 'console logging' and confirmed that `pagesController.index` is called for each non-API route but `'/'`.

routes.js

```
'use strict';

var controllers = require('./controllers');
var v1Router = require('./routes/api/v1');

var pagesController = controllers.pagesController;

module.exports = function(app) {

  app.use('/api', v1Router);

  app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
  });

  app.get(['*'],
    pagesController.index
  );
};
```

pages.js

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');

var index = function(req, res) {
  if (req.user) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../assets', 'index.html'));
  } else {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../assets', 'signin.html'));
  }
};

module.exports = {
  index: index
};
```

Update: I changed my root from `/` to `/a` in my client-side routing and everything works perfectly. For whatever reason `/` is not being run through `pagesController.index`.

Update 2: So this line in my `app.js` is causing the issue:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));
```

With that line removed `pagesController.index` is properly called on `/`, however none of my static assets are served so simply removing that line does not solve it. How can I serve my static assets properly while ignoring `index.html`?

Comment: which version of express?

Comment: @ChrisL Express 4.12.4

Comment: Do you have a "/" route anywhere? Try putting app.get('/', function(req, res) {...}); above the catch-all route?

Comment: @ChrisL, I figured out what line of code is causing the issue, but still not sure how to solve it. See update 2 above if you have a chance.

Comment: I think your answer is here. http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html I think this part is the key: The files will be looked up in the order the static directories were set using the express.static middleware. So, use the middleware/directories multiple times to serve static assets and arrange them in the order you wish them called? Or use the 'virtual path' to serve your angular from. app.use('/angularPath', express.static('public')); and place it above other static routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also handle the route in your conditional statements:

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');

var index = function(req, res) {
   if (req.user) {
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../assets', 'index.html'));
   } if (req.url === '/') {
     ** Handle Case Here **
   }
  else {
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../assets', 'signin.html'));
   }
 };

 module.exports = {
   index: index
 };
```

Ok, I did some research: A great article and possible solution here:(not sure if it fits your use case)

http://evanhahn.com/express-dot-static-deep-dive/

```
app.use(express.static(myStaticPath, {
  index: ['jokes.txt', 'index.html']
})
```

You can simply give an array of files to serve as index, if the first is found it is served, if not, the second is served, and so on.